# Create a audio object by using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, audio

I need to create the popup window and insert some content by using the JavaScript coding.

Now, my web page will show the pop-up when some function(CamanJS) processed.
The function will output the Image in DataUrl form.And show it in the pop-up

```
var w=window.open('about:blank','image from canvas');
w.document.write("<img src='"+this.toBase64()+"' alt='from canvas'/>");
```

I want to insert a audio with 5 second into the pop-up. And than played the audio will execute the Function2().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the binary file into base64 string and decode. Here's an example in PHP for encoding:

```
function encodedAudioString($type, $file) {
    return 'data:audio/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
}
```

If you want to encode and decode in a browser, you need to request the file with XHR as arrayBuffer. Check this link for full code: https://github.com/dondido/MP3-to-Base64-Encoder-and-Decoder/blob/master/index.html

Then you can embed the dataURI string as the src of an `audio` element:

```
<audio controls src="data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAA..........8l3KcK">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a wav or ogg vorbis file, have a AUDIO HTML element reference it, initially stopped, and have it play through JavaScript.